# Set Current Timestamp with JQuery

Tags: jquery, timestamp

help me to set current time, with a timestamp

```
var defaults = $.extend({
        start: '1503113104',
        end: '1505235600',
        now: , // here i have to set current timestamp
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish a Unix timestamp in seconds, you have to get the time from a `new Date()`, divide it by 1000 (since that is in milliseconds) and remove the decimals using `Math.floor()`.

```
var defaults = $.extend({
  start: '1503113104',
  end: '1505235600',
  now: Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000), // Unix timestamp in seconds (instead of milliseconds)
```

I assumed you wish it in seconds because I noticed your other times have 3 digits missing...

If you want them to be evaluated as integers... You probably should remove the quotes around them.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a solution for your every problem related to timestamp**

This is a multi-purpose solution.

```js
var dt = new Date();
var h =  dt.getHours(), m = (dt.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + dt.getMinutes();
var strDate = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dt.getDate();
var currentTime = (h > 12) ? (h-12 + ':' + m +' PM') : (h + ':' + m +' AM');
var currDate = "'"+strDate+"'";
var currentTimeStamp = Date.parse(currDate + currentTime);
console.log(currentTimeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.now()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/) for that. Read jquery docs for more informations..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date`

```
 var currentTime = new Date();

 current timestamp = Date.parse(currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var defaults = $.extend({
        start: '1503113104',
        end: '1505235600',
        now:  Math.round(+new Date()/1000), // unix timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy code is `new Date().valueOf()

```js
console.log(new Date().valueOf());
```

`